# TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserName' of undefined with Angular 2

Tags: angular, .net-core, webapi2

I would like to display a username of the current user in my angular 2 application. The backend is developed with .net core web api.

I write this code but obtain in console this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserName' of undefined

**class AuthService**

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {AuthHttp} from "./auth.http";
import {User} from "./user";

@Injectable()

export class AuthService {
    authKey = "auth";

    constructor(private http: AuthHttp) {
    }

    // Persist auth into localStorage or removes it if a NULL argument is given
    setAuth(auth: any): boolean {
        if (auth) {
            localStorage.setItem(this.authKey, JSON.stringify(auth));
        }
        else {
            localStorage.removeItem(this.authKey);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Retrieves the auth JSON object (or NULL if none)
    getAuth(): any {
        var i = localStorage.getItem(this.authKey);
        if (i) {
            return JSON.parse(i);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns TRUE if the user is logged in, FALSE otherwise.

    isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return localStorage.getItem(this.authKey) != null;
    }

    **get() {
        return this.http.get("api/Accounts")
            .map(response => <User>response.json());
    }**

}
```

I'm sure that the user is logged in because I can read the his token.

**Web api method**

```
 /// <summary>
        /// GET: api/accounts
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A Json-serialized object representing the current account.</returns>
        [HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var id = GetCurrentUserId(); 
            //var id = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            var user = DbContext.Users.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null) return new JsonResult(new UserViewModel()
            {
                Type = user.Type,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                Email = user.Email,
                DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
                DisplayPhoneNumber = user.DisplayPhoneNumber,
                Description = user.Description

            }, DefaultJsonSettings);
            else return NotFound(new { error = String.Format("User ID {0} has not been found", id) });
        }
```

**class user in typescript**

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public Type: number,
        public UserName: string,
        public DisplayName: string,
        public PhoneNumber: string,
        public DisplayPhoneNumber: boolean,
        public Description: string,
        public Password: string,
        public PasswordNew: string,
        public Email: string
    ) {
    }
}
```

**Code of component in angular 2**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";
import {AuthHttp} from "./auth.http";
import {User} from "./user";

@Component({
    selector: "home",
    templateUrl: "templates/home.component.html",
    //template: `<h1>Home Component</h1>`
})

export class HomeComponent {

    isRegister: boolean;
    currentUser: User;
    constructor(
        public router: Router,
        public authService: AuthService,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {

        //this.isRegister = this.authService.isLoggedIn();
        //console.log(this.isRegister);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.authService.get().subscribe(
                User => this.currentUser = User
            );           
            console.log(this.isRegister);
            console.log(this.currentUser.UserName);               
        }
    }
}
```

**Code template html**

```
 <div *ngIf="currentUser"><h1>{{currentUser.UserName}}</h1></div>
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: console.log(this.currentUser.UserName); Does that line log the username correctly?

Comment: in this point console.log(this.currentUser.UserName);  the console write undefined

Comment: Is the username displaying correctly in your template? If it is, then Bougarfaoui El houcine got it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'are trying to access the `this.currentUser.UserName` before `this.authService.get()` resolves `User` value, because `this.authService.get` is asynchronous, so do this :

```
     ngOnInit() {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.authService.get().subscribe(
                User => {
                  this.currentUser = User
                  console.log(this.isRegister);
                  console.log(this.currentUser.UserName);
            });           

        }
    }
```

Comment: ´ <div *ngIf="currentUser"><h1>{{currentUser?.UserName}}</h1></div> ´ I try this but doesn't work

Comment: I don't think so, at the first time `this.currentUser` is undefined, and when you are trying to access a property of `undefined` an error will be thrown.

Comment: @Cicciux did you try my solution ?

Comment: Yes I tried and work fine.. but so the problem is in console.log , because I call it out of  authService.get() ???

Comment: yes exaclty `console.log` will be executed before `authService.get()` has resolved the `User ` because it's asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace:

`currentUser: User;`

as

`currentUser = new User();`

Undefined error in console is disappeared.